# Selenium java. Comparing two given strings with returning exact place where the error is happened

Tags: java, selenium, equals

Не могу додумать, как написать тест, чтобы выводило не просто "true/false", а чтоб показывало конкретное несоответсвие в тексте.
Соответсвенно, просто equals не работает.

Comment: Самый простой вариант - перебирать эти две строки в цикле и "запоминать" позиции когда символы разные.

Comment: Приглядитесь к расстояниям Левенштейна, если Вам нужно найти все различия между строками и к идее @Евгения Быкова, если достаточно найти первую отличающуюся позицию

Answer (score 0):

Идёшь в цикле, берёшь символ из первого текста и из второго. Если совпадают - идёшь дальше, если отличаются - помечаешь(например, сохраняя в список позицию отличия). Если одна строка закончилась раньше другой - помечай всю оставшуюся строку.

Если текст большой, и нужна оптимизация - храни не конкретные позиции отличающихся символов, а диапазон. Например:

1.) "Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку"

2.) "Шла Саша по мосту и сосала сушку"

В неоптимизированном варианте у тебя в списке окажется: [12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

В оптимизированном: ["12-16"].

Как хранить диапазон, оставлю на твои раздумья. Можно в виде массива строк с отделением через '-', можно с помощью объекта с двумя полями, можно...

Comment: А что делать, если строки совпадают полностью, но при этом одна из них имеет лишний символ на первой же позиции?) Вы получите отличия вообще во всех символах, тогда как реальное отличие только в одном!

Comment: Тогда задача звучит слегка по другому, и сделать её сложнее... Но вы уже ответили в комментарии, над чем можно подумать)